# Использование JS и SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Вопрос касается **JS + SVG**. Долго думал сюда написать, но уже несколько дней не могу найти решение, прошу помочь разобраться.

Примерный код я напишу внизу, но суть следующая: есть обёртка, в которой находятся 2 элемента, картинка и иконка из `SVG`. Иконка спозицирнирована абсолютно (в примерном коде будет иначе) поверх картинки. При наведении на картинку иконка меняется посредством замены пути в `USE`. При клике на обёртку должно рпоисходить некое действие.

На практике же у меня получается либо изменить иконку, либо выполнить действие при клике. Конечно, можно заменить `SVG` и картинку единой картинкой, которая меняется при наведении курсора посредством `CSS`, но я бы предпочёл всё же `SVG`. Ради интереса пробовал на цветных квадратах всё делать и заметил, что если менять цвет квадрата через свойства `CSS` (`..style.backgroundColor` и даже картинки можно), то клик работает. Также пробовал использовать `setTimeout`, но использование под вопросом, т.к. задержка при наведении срабатывает, да и клик не всегда пройдёт, прям русская рулетка. А чтобы боле менее проходила, нужна и задержка нормальная.

В общем, идеи иссякли, если знаете что нужно дописать, подскажите.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var image = document.querySelector(".image");
var icon_svg = document.querySelector(".icon-svg");

image.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if (!icon_svg.firstElementChild.classList.contains('#play_icon_active')) {
     icon_svg.firstElementChild.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'svg_sprite.svg#play_icon_active');
  }
});

image.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  icon_svg.firstElementChild.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'svg_sprite.svg#play_icon');
});

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("OK");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.icon-svg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="svg_sprite.svg">
</object>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <svg class="icon-svg">
               <use xlink:href="svg_sprite.svg#play_icon">
               </use>
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы напишите пожалуйста, чего вы хотите добиться? Пока что вы описали проблему, а что вы хотите сделать - не понятно.

Comment: На сайте есть блок, в котором находится картинка с подписью. При наведении мыши на картинку, иконка сменятся на другую, а при клике (хоть на картинку, хоть на текст) открывается видео. Т.е., просто добавляю классы другим блокам. И проблема в том, что если я прописываю события при наведении/отведении, клик не срабатывает по иконке, что есть косяк. А если не прописываю события, то клик проходит.

Comment: Более менее стало понятно. Тогда добавьте актуальный код, который не работает. А то ваш пример кода работает же.

Comment: Но...у меня этот код не работает. У Вас видна иконка проигрывателя на синем квадрате, расположенном на зелёном?

Хорошо, вот мой разминочный макет, там под картинкой тот самый блок имеется, и на нём не срабатывает клик открытия видео, хотя если кликнуть чуть в стороне - оно открывается.

http://w91340ks.beget.tech

Comment: Я не писал код SVG, поэтому было недопонимание, но сейчас, надеюсь, будет понятно

Comment: Я в вашем примере не вижу иконки проигрывателя `svg`, потому что в примере у вас нету кода для `svg`. Тем не менее, событие клик работает нормально.

Comment: Извините, не могу открыть ваш сайт http://prntscr.com/joe35h. Пожалуйста, приведите пример не работающего кода в вопросе.

Comment: Да, эту страничку, почему-то, антивирусы не любят, сам не знаю почему. Но в том-то и проблема, что я не знаю как саму проблему передать, т.к. SVG-спрайты идут отдельным файлом, а подключение через тег object будет работать только с сервера. Тут либо через node.js проверять, либо уже с готового сервера, как я это уже сделал выше. Исходный код будет как и в самом начале вопроса, практически, только ещё со спрайтом. Попробовал набрать код на ресурсах, чтобы хотя бы ссылочку скинуть, но и там иконки не отображаются.

Могу только написать содержимое нужных 2 иконок из SVG:

Comment: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol id="play_icon" viewBox="0 0 171 170"><circle fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="14" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="86" cy="85" r="77.5"/><circle opacity=".35" fill="#138ACE" cx="85.5" cy="84.5" r="75.5"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M58.5 121.9L128 85.6 58.6 48.9z"/></symbol><symbol id="play_icon_active" viewBox="0 0 169.8 170"><circle fill="none" stroke="#2b93d4" stroke-width="14" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="84.8" cy="85" r="77.5"/><circle opacity=".4" fill="#fff" cx="84.3" cy="84.5" r="75.5"/>

Comment: <path fill="#2b93d4" d="M57.3 121.9l69.5-36.3-69.4-36.7z"/></symbol></svg>

Comment: Вы бы этот код иконок в вопрос-то добавили, все так комментарии для такого не предназначены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разметка не совсем такая, как у вас, но проблема понятна.

Дело в том, что у вас не верно условие `if (!icon_svg.firstElementChild.classList.contains('#play_icon_active'))`. Из-за этого постоянно срабатывает событие `mouseover` и меняет атрибут, как следствие клик просто не происходит.

Решение:

- Написать правильное условие.
- На всякий случай использовать для `.icon-svg` стиль `pointer-events: none;` что бы событие клика не обращало внимание на `svg`.

Пример.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var image = document.querySelector(".image");
var icon_svg = document.querySelector(".icon-svg")

image.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if (icon_svg.firstElementChild.getAttribute('href') !== '#play_icon_active') {
    icon_svg.firstElementChild.setAttribute('href', '#play_icon_active');
  }
});

image.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  icon_svg.firstElementChild.setAttribute('href', '#play_icon');
});

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("OK");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.icon-svg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Делаем "прозрачным" для событий*/
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="play_icon" viewBox="0 0 171 170"><circle fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="14" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="86" cy="85" r="77.5"/><circle opacity=".35" fill="#138ACE" cx="85.5" cy="84.5" r="75.5"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M58.5 121.9L128 85.6 58.6 48.9z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="play_icon_active" viewBox="0 0 169.8 170"><circle fill="none" stroke="#2b93d4" stroke-width="14" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="84.8" cy="85" r="77.5"/><circle opacity=".4" fill="#fff" cx="84.3" cy="84.5" r="75.5"/>
  <path fill="#2b93d4" d="M57.3 121.9l69.5-36.3-69.4-36.7z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <svg class="icon-svg">
       <use href="#play_icon" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Исправил, заработало! Спасибо большое!!!